# Using map, iterator and nullptr

Tags: c++

**Introduction**

I'm trying to create an idempotent function. 
To do this I check if there is content on the map and after that it may be necessary add content or not.

**Code**

```
  std::map<char,int> mymap;
  std::map<char,int>::iterator it;

  mymap['a']=50;

  it = mymap.find('a');
  int value = it->second;
```

**Question 1** How do I know if `it` value isn't `null`? How do I get the iterator's value?

**Question 2** How do I know if `it->second` value isn't `null`?

**Question 3** How I return a `null` value and compare it with a `std::string / container`?

**Example Question 3**

```
if(get_client_from_map(id) == nullptr){
   // do anything
}else{
  // code anything here too
}
```

> *Note*: get_client_from_map(id) returns (it->second) result, it can be std::string or null/nullptr.

Comment: `map::find` returns `map::end()` if the value could not be found, so you want `if (it != mymap.end()) cout << "found"; else cout << "not found";`

Comment: 1. Explained in the [std::map documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) 2. `int` cannot be `NULL` 3. Return an std::string* and check for `NULL`.

Comment: now I understand, thanks.

Comment: Note that for containers, "empty" (size==0) is often a better choice than null. This includes strings; it's rarely needed to distinguish between the empty string and no string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I know if it value isn't null? How do I get the iterator's value?

If not found, [std::map::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) will returns [std::map::end()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/end).

> How do I know if it->second value isn't null?

It could not be nullptr, because it is a `int`.

> How I return a null value and compare it with a std::string / container?

If you want to return `nullptr`, the value type must be some kind of pointer, such as `int *`, or `std::string *`.

Comment: isn't recomended return nullptr ?

Comment: @Urbester It can't. If you want to use `nullptr`, the value type must be some kind of pointer, such as `int *`, or `std::string *`.

Comment: Instead of returning `nullptr`, consider using the hopefully-soon-to-be-part-of-the-standard [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional). If your compiler doesn't have it yet, [Boost will help you out](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1 How do I know if it value isn't null? How do I get the iterator's value?**

If you took a look at the documentation of std::map.find http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/ you will see that it returns `end()` if it can't find the element with the specified key.

**Question 2 How do I know if it->second value isn't null?**

Since you're using `int` as mapped value, the value is never null, ints are zero initialized in maps when used with `[]`, otherwise, just check for it `if(it->second) { // not null}`.

**Question 3 How I return a null value and compare it with a std::string?**

Use an empty string for that.

Comment: I can't compare nullstr with containers?